# Multiple Stores in multiple servers

Tags: configuration, multistore

I have a doubt referent a Multiple Stores in Magento.

There's a way to setup multiple stores in multiple servers?

**For example:**

```
www.store1.com in server1
www.store2.com in server2
```

But I wanna share the same admin with both...

So, what's the possibility to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you achieve this? If yes, can you share your experience? Thanks

Comment: Why not use a traditional setup where you have one Magento installation and two servers with a load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

I am notsure,but you can try this.

First copy all files to server2 from server1 and always to copy file to both server.Make server1 as base system from where you can admin.

Admin is always with www.store1.com/adminurl.You need sync files from server1 to server2 and need share same db server.

On second  server server2, for run server2 you need to change at index.php

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

to

```
    Mage::run('SECOND_SERVER_CODE', 'store');


/* it will store_view/store/website be depends on configuration */
```

NOte: System>configuration all scope you need set  url store base secure
 and unsecure url,media,skin,js url should be store1 url.Only need to change
those store2 scope.

This make all file upload at server1.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is one magento installation with two websites and two webnodes.

I don't see any reason why you want to direct domain1 to server1 and domain2 to server2, either have one server or if you need more, put a load balancer before and have more web nodes.

But then you have to solve the problems like:

- session sharing
- one cache
- one media directory
- etc.